# How can I repeatedly edit data (a scalar value) at various locations (row_index, column_index) in an existing excel file using Pandas (in Python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I initially made an empty excel file with column names (5 columns in each sheet) and sheet names (4 sheets with names).
When I tried to write data (a scalar value at a time, say 5) in an excel sheet using ExcelWriter, to_excel in Pandas. It deletes the previous data as well as deletes other sheets.

I don't want to aggregate the data in a variable and write it at once. Because this is a part of a time-consuming experiment and I want to save data regularly.

If the same can be done with normal python (without pandas), kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

From [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter), you need to create an `ExcelWriter` which opens the Excel file in append mode:

```
with ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet_name')
```

Comment: But we can only append using append mode. What I want to know is whether we can edit data at a particular location, that location can be anywhere in between also, not just the end.